# Excel VBA: ComboBox_Click event is firing for any change on any worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a complex application and I stripped it down to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the problem.

There is one worksheet Labor with a combobox named ComboBoxRatesSelected.

This combobox has a RowSource on sheet Parameters, and it has a LinkedCell on sheet Parameters.

The code module for sheet Labor has an event handler for ComboBoxRatesSelected_Click. I have stripped down this event handler so that it has only one line of code, a MsgBox.

Whenever any change is made to any cell on any worksheet, the event handler is triggered twice. This happens even though the combobox is not clicked, and there is no code that changes the combobox. The only code in the entire workbook is the Click handler for the combobox mentioned above.

The only time I have ever seen unintended triggering of an event is if other code changes the value in the control, which will trigger a Click event. However, this stripped-down version rules that out.

File available here: www.seiglefamily.com/data/ComboBoxFiresEvenWhenNotTouched.xlsm

Crossposted:
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1186999-combobox_click-event-is-firing-for-any-change-on-any-worksheet.html
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?59577-ComboBox_Click-event-is-firing-for-any-change-on-any-worksheet&p=362039